# Google App Script - changeType "REMOVE_GRID"

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

I'm using a Google spreadsheet.  I'm attempting to create an `onChange` trigger that will activate a script when any sheet is added or deleted. I was able to get the script to work when a new sheet is added using `changeType === "INSERT_GRID"`. However when I'm using `changeType === "REMOVE_GRID"` the script does not activate when a sheet is deleted. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what `REMOVE_GRID` does?

Here is a simplified version of what I was trying to achieve:

```
function deleteSheet(e) {
  if (e.changeType === "REMOVE_GRID") {      
e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(1, 1).setValue("Deleted a sheet");
  }
}
```

I did change the trigger to: `deleteSheet --> spreadsheet --> onChange`

Any help would be appreciated! Also this is my first time posting so I apologize in advance for any formatting errors. Thanks!

Comment: Add the execution transcript.

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user 21 times.

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see what type of event is getting passed into that trigger by adding:

`Browser.msgBox(Utilities.jsonStringify(e))`

at the top.  This will also confirm that the function is getting triggered.

From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17750589/google-apps-event-changetype-undefined-in-google-sheet/17751347#17751347

Comment: Thanks you!  Tried adding that in and see what appears.  Showing up as "REMOVE_GRID" whenever I delete a sheet (as it should).  I'm using a conditional statement and it's evaluating as true but it does not execute the commands.  Very frustrating.

The strange thing is that it appears to work/execute for all other types of changeTypes (INSERT_ROW, INSERT_COLUMN, etc.).  So this works:

if (e.changeType === "INSERT_GRID") {
e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(1, 1).setValue("Deleted a sheet");}

But if I change it to "REMOVE_GRID", it doesn't execute the command.  Thanks!

Comment: Are there any errors in the logs?  You can turn on immediate error notifications from where you set up the trigger

Comment: maybe there is an issue w/ your code inside the conditional?  You can add the browser box inside the conditional to see if it's getting triggered.  Or maybe `e.source` isn't what you think it is?