# Cell formula which returns the number of sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-custom-function

I'm trying to add some "validation" to a google sheet to prevent errors from creeping in as the sheet is edited (think assertion when programming).

Because of the way my sheet is structured to do this validation it would be useful to know the number of sheets in the current workbook. Is it possible to do this?

## Approaches tried:

### Excel-compatible function

Excel provides the functions `=SHEETS()` for this purpose (https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sheet-function). But this function doesn't exist in sheets

### Custom function

[This post on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/googlesheets/comments/do75j3/counting_number_of_sheets_in_a_workbook/) suggests using the following functions in scripts:

```
function getNumSheets() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().length;
}
```

This works - but it doesn't get updated when the number of sheets change - unless you force it to recalculate.

I'm leaning towards doing my validation "in code" rather than in the equation language and running it every time I want to do my tests....

Answer (score 1):

In Google Sheets, custom functions are recalculated when one of its parameters change. NOTE: They don't allow volatile functions (NOW, TODAY, RANDOM, etc.)

In order to get the current number of sheets on something close to real time, instead of using a custom function you might use a change installable trigger (usually referred as `onChange`) as it's triggered, among other cases, when a new sheet is inserted and when a sheet is deleted.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-scripts/guides/sheets/functions
- https://developers.google.com/apps-scripts/guides/triggers/installable
- https://developers.google.com/apps-scripts/guides/events

Related

- [How to update this formula so it automatically updates?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/122810/88163)
- [Google App Script - changeType "REMOVE_GRID"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/118317/88163)

Comment: Taht seems like a reasonable idea... can I get the function to invalidate "on change" or would I have to dig around in sheet and cause a recalculation myself?

Comment: Links fixed. Triggers can't be "invalidated", what is usually done is to add `if..else` statements to control what should be executed when the required conditions are met.

Comment: Thanks. By invalidated I mean "recalculate all the cells which use this function". It feels more natural to have `=numSheets()` in a sell somewhere, rather than have cells magically update on change.

Comment: I don't think that "invalidated" is a correct term for what are trying to say... anyway, you might use the *onChange* trigger to search for all the cells having that function to "force a recalculation" by changing a parameter (it could be a sequential number, toggling a value i.e. changing 1 to 0 then on the next execution change 0 to 1..). Another way commonly used is to clear the cell having the function, execute **flush** then add again the formula. If you need further help, please post a new question.